# Complexity of individual in NEAT-Python

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, neat

When I was programming with NEAT-Python and finishing my experiment I got this message about an individual from the NEAT reporter. What do the numbers after complexity mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This prints the `size` attribute for a genome. Quoting from the [documentation](https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/genome-interface.html?highlight=complexity#speciation-misc):

> Returns a measure of genome complexity. This object is currently only given to reporters at the end of a generation to indicate the complexity of the highest-fitness genome. In the DefaultGenome class, this method currently returns (number of nodes, number of enabled connections).

Note: You can find this by consulting the source code for [reporting](https://neat-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/reporting.html?highlight=complexity#), whcih shows that the `size` attribute of the best solution is what is being printed

```py
    def found_solution(self, config, generation, best):
        print('\nBest individual in generation {0} meets fitness threshold - complexity: {1!r}'.format(
            self.generation, best.size()))
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I am still unsure about one thing unfortunately. Do the number of nodes represent the output nodes? Cause I defined 1120 input nodes and 12 Output nodes in the configuration file.